# Join strings which are in a colum

Tags: excel, awk, sed

Anyone can help on below pls.

Here is case

I have a column with hostnames
Say :

```
Host1
Host2
..
..
```

I need to set bigpanda maintenance plan

```
host = host1* OR host2* OR ....
```

Comment: or expand this as needed: ="host = "&A1&"* OR "&A2&"* OR "

Comment: YMMV if you expect people to know what `set bigpanda maintenance plan` means, you should explain what that means. Add your attempt to solve your problem yourself so we can help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for Excel solution then could try `TEXTJOIN()`.

```
=TEXTJOIN("* OR ",1,A1:A13)&"* OR"
```

[image]